# Jquery, line in callback function doesnt wait execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a nice animation where a paragraph fade, change the content, unfade, change again and so on. the thing is the line where I set the paragraph content got executed before the fade-unfading things finished.

```
function displayAnim(x){
    let textBox = document.getElementById("resultBoxText");
    fadeO(textBox,x,0);
}
function fadeO(elem,x,i){
    $("#resultBoxText").fadeIn("2000",next(elem,x,i));
}

function next(elem,x,i){
    elem.innerHTML = result[x][i]; //this line got executed well, but it executed 5 times already even before the first unfade happens
    let nextI = i+1;
    if(nextI >= 6){
        $("#resultBoxText").fadeOut("2000",show(x));
        return;
    }else{
        $("#resultBoxText").fadeOut("2000",fadeO(elem,x,nextI));
    }
}

function show(x){
    let textBox = document.getElementById("resultBoxText");
    textBox.innerHTML = result[x][6] //it reach this line already. this line is supossed to be executed after the fades occur 5 times
}
```

what am I doing wrong?
thanks (^_^)

Comment: How are the functions called? Also, it might help to include your HTML and/or CSS code to make a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Shouldn't the function on the third line read `fadeOut()` instead of `fadeO()`.